# Build ffmpeg on Android. Using NEON (Tegra3) and Cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, cygwin, neon

I have some issues building ffmpeg for Android using NEON instructions (for Tegra3).
I am able to create the libffmpeg.so WITHOUT the optmization : -mfpu=neon

I am using lastest ffmpeg 0.11.1 with Cygwin on Windows.

Please find below the build.sh file i'm using (found on the web and tweaked)

```
#!/bin/bash
export TMPDIR=C:/Arnaud/Private/Android/temp
NDK=C:/Arnaud/Private/Android/android-ndk-r8b
###Path for Android 8
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows

function build_one
{
./configure --target-os=linux \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
    --enable-asm \
    --enable-neon \
    --arch=armv7 \
    --cpu=cortex-a8 \
    --enable-memalign-hack \
    --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
    --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
    --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
    --extra-cflags="$OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS" \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-memalign-hack \
    --enable-static \
    --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" \
    --disable-everything \
    --enable-demuxer=mov \
    --enable-demuxer=h264 \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --enable-protocols \
    --enable-avformat \
    --enable-avcodec \
    --enable-decoder=rawvideo \
    --enable-decoder=mjpeg \
    --enable-decoder=h263 \
    --enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
    --enable-decoder=h264 \
    --enable-parser=h264 \
    --disable-network \
    --enable-zlib \
    --disable-avfilter \
    --disable-avdevice \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

sed -i 's/HAVE_LRINT 0/HAVE_LRINT 1/g' config.h
sed -i 's/HAVE_LRINTF 0/HAVE_LRINTF 1/g' config.h
sed -i 's/HAVE_ROUND 0/HAVE_ROUND 1/g' config.h
sed -i 's/HAVE_ROUNDF 0/HAVE_ROUNDF 1/g' config.h
sed -i 's/HAVE_TRUNC 0/HAVE_TRUNC 1/g' config.h
sed -i 's/HAVE_TRUNCF 0/HAVE_TRUNCF 1/g' config.h

make clean
make  -j4 install

#Old Prebuilt (R8)
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar d libavcodec/libavcodec.a inverse.o
$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld -rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -soname libffmpeg.so -shared -nostdlib  -z,noexecstack -Bsymbolic --whole-archive --no-undefined -o $PREFIX/libffmpeg.so libavcodec/libavcodec.a libavformat/libavformat.a libavutil/libavutil.a libswscale/libswscale.a -lc -lm -lz -ldl -llog  --warn-once  --dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker $PREBUILT/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/libgcc.a
}

#arm v7n
CPU=armv7-a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS='-I$PLATFORM/usr/include -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300'
PREFIX=./android/$CPU 
build_one
```

With this option, on optimize_cflags, **-mfpu=neon**, the build fails with those errors:

CP      ffprobe
STRIP   ffprobe
INSTALL install-progs-yes
INSTALL ffprobe
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(fft_fixed_init_arm.o): In function `ff_fft_fixed_init_arm':
C:\Arnaud\Private\Android\DVBStream\jni\ffmpeg-0.11.1/libavcodec/arm/fft_fixed_init_arm.c:36: undefined reference to`ff_fft_fixed_calc_neon'
libavcodec/libavcodec.a(fft_init_arm.o): In function `ff_fft_init_arm':
C:\Arnaud\Private\Android\DVBStream\jni\ffmpeg-0.11.1/libavcodec/arm/fft_init_arm.c:47: undefined reference to`ff_fft_permute_neon'
C:\Arnaud\Private\Android\DVBStream\jni\ffmpeg-0.11.1/libavcodec/arm/fft_init_arm.c:47: undefined reference to `ff_fft_calc_neon'

Seems that some dependencies are missing / not set. Do you have any clue what's happening / how to build with neon?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the libavcodec was not compiled with neon support enabled?  This may be a matter of telling autoconf to enable the preprocessor to include the NEON support.